# android osmdroid change local language to english

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap

I'm using OSM for android map. And I need map show all label in english not local language. Is that possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should have a look `OnlineTileSourceBase` because what you are asking looks like related to request header in online tile provider request header. You might have to implement onlinetilesourcebase to add locale information for insisting on eng

Comment: Ofcourse if there is no other chance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it would be possible on OSM for Android. Support for i18n is not something default, but rather what the render might expect. Specifically for rendered maps (such as what you see on openstreetmap.org home page) there is no support directly from OSM, but there's some effort, as you can see the (experimental!) maps on this website: http://toolserver.org/~osm/locale/

You may find more information about maps i18n in [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but now I was assigned moving to develop iphone app. So, I did not working on osm anymore.

Comment: @majorl3oat you can also use OSM maps on iPhone - check [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Libraries_that_help_iPhone_developers_use_OSM_maps) for more information.